# python loops and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Question: Create a program that allows the user to enter 10 different integers. If the user tries to enter
an integer that has already been entered, the program will alert the user immediately and
prompt the user to enter another integer. When 10 different integers have been entered,
the average of these 10 integers is displayed.

This is my code:

```
mylist = []
number = int(input("Enter value: "))
mylist.append(number)
while len(mylist) != 10:
    number = int(input("Enter value: "))
    if number in mylist:
        number = int(input("The number is already in the list, enter another number: "))
        mylist.append(number)
    else:
        mylist.append(number)

print(sum(mylist)/float(len(mylist)))
```

This kind of works but I need to create a loop that will keep on asking the user for another number if the number is in the array. Can you help?

Comment: You are still appending the number the list even though it is already in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
mylist = []
number = int(input("Enter value: ")) mylist.append(number)
while len(mylist) != 10:
    number = int(input("Enter value: "))
    while number in mylist:
        number = int(input("The number is already in the list, enter another number: "))
    mylist.append(number)
print(sum(mylist)/float(len(mylist)))
```